Is there a way to fix the delay before the image appears?
I'm using this code to create simple reader. In my reader I have image view to show images and text label to show text on screen. Everything works fine, but when I launch the app and start turning pages, I experience a slight delay of a few seconds before the next page appears. But if I scroll forward through all the pages. Then I'll scroll back all the pages. And again I’ll start flipping through the pages forward. Then this delay of a few seconds will disappear. Is there a way to fix this delay? Maybe I need to somehow pre-load the images?
ReaderController
class ReaderController: UIViewController {
    
    var pagesData = [PageData]()
    var index = Int()
    var pageIndex: Int = -1
    
    let pageContainer: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    let pageViews: [PageLayout] = {
        let view = [PageLayout(), PageLayout()]
        view[0].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view[1].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()

        pageViews[0].index = index
        pageViews[1].index = index
        pageViews[0].pageIndex = pageIndex
        pageViews[1].pageIndex = pageIndex
        
        pageTransition(animated: false, direction: "fromRight")
    }
        
    func setupViews() {
        pageContainer.addSubview(pageViews[0])
        pageContainer.addSubview(pageViews[1])
        view.addSubview(pageContainer)
    }
        
    func setupConstraints() {
        pageContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        pageContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        pageContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        pageContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        pageViews[0].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
        pageViews[0].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        pageViews[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        pageViews[0].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        pageViews[1].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
        pageViews[1].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        pageViews[1].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        pageViews[1].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageContainer.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
        
    func loadData(fileName: Any) -> PagesData {
        var url = NSURL()
        url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "text", withExtension: "json")! as NSURL
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        let person = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PagesData.self, from: data)
        return person
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: view.self)

            if view.safeAreaInsets.left > 30 {
                if (location.x > self.view.frame.size.width - (view.safeAreaInsets.left * 1.5)) {
                    pageTransition(animated: true, direction: "fromRight")
                } else if (location.x < (view.safeAreaInsets.left * 1.5)) {
                    pageTransition(animated: true, direction: "fromLeft")
                }
            }

            else {
                if (location.x > self.view.frame.size.width - 40) {
                    pageTransition(animated: true, direction: "fromRight")
                } else if (location.x < 40) {
                    pageTransition(animated: true, direction: "fromLeft")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func pageTransition(animated: Bool, direction: String) {
        let result = loadData(fileName: pagesData)

        switch direction {
        case "fromRight":
            pageIndex += 1
        case "fromLeft":
            pageIndex -= 1
        default: break
        }

        pageViews[0].pageIndex = pageIndex
        pageViews[1].pageIndex = pageIndex

        if pageIndex <= -1 {
            pageIndex = 0
        } else if pageIndex >= result.pagesData.count {
            pageIndex = result.pagesData.count - 1
        } else {

            let fromView = pageViews[0].isHidden ? pageViews[1] : pageViews[0]
            let toView = pageViews[0].isHidden ? pageViews[0] : pageViews[1]
            toView.configure(theData: result.pagesData[pageIndex])
            fromView.isHidden = true
            toView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    
}

PageLayout
class PageLayout: UIView {
    
    var index = Int()
    var pageIndex = Int()
    
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()

    var imageViewTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var imageViewBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var imageViewLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var imageViewTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    
    private let textLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "ComicSansMS-Bold", size: 19)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        label.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        label.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        return label
    }()

    var textLabelTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var textLabelBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var textLabelLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var textLabelTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(imageView)
        addSubview(textLabel)
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not happening")
    }
    
    func setupConstraints() {
        imageViewTopConstraint = imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        imageViewBottomConstraint = imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        imageViewLeadingConstraint = imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        imageViewTrailingConstraint = imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        addConstraints([imageViewTopConstraint, imageViewBottomConstraint, imageViewLeadingConstraint, imageViewTrailingConstraint])
        
        textLabelTopConstraint = imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        textLabelBottomConstraint = imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        textLabelLeadingConstraint = imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        textLabelTrailingConstraint = imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        addConstraints([textLabelTopConstraint, textLabelBottomConstraint, textLabelLeadingConstraint, textLabelTrailingConstraint])
    }
        
    func configure(theData: PageData) {
        textLabel.text = theData.textData
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "page\(pageIndex+1)")
    }
    
}

